# Add button in Orders grid in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, column

I want add a button or a action in a column in the Orders grid. When I press the button I want to call a method from a controller (or a helper).

My first problem:
I want to remain in the page of the Orders grid and not open the url of the controller.

My second problem:
The method of the controller returns a string. I want to display that string in an alert box.

I tried using a rendeder but I can't solve my two problems.

I added a new column to Order grid using the observer:

config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
     <events>
        <adminhtml_block_html_before>
            <observers>
                <name>
                  <class>VendorName_ModuleName_Model_ObserverAddColumn</class>
                    <method>addColumnToGrid</method>
                </name>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_block_html_before>
        </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Observer:

```
<?php

class VendorName_ModuleName_Model_ObserverAddColumn
{
    public function addColumnToGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $javascript = "
                   alert('hello');
                ";

    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    // Check whether the loaded block is the orders grid block
    if (!($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid) || $block->getNameInLayout() != 'sales_order.grid')
        return $this;

    // Add a new column rigth after the "view" column
    $block->addColumnAfter('view', [
        'header' => $block->__('Header'),
        'width' => '60px',
        'index' => 'index_example',
        'type'   => 'action',
        'sortable' => false,
        'getter'   => 'getId',
        //'renderer' => 'VendorName_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Template_Grid_Renderer_CreateInvoiceRenderer',
        'actions'   => array(
                array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('ModuleName')->__('Create Invoice'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> 'routerName/controllerName/actionName'),
                    //'onclick' => 'window.location = "' . Mage::getUrl('routerName/controllerName/actionName') . '"',
                        //'target'=>'',
                    //'onclick' => $javascript,
                        'field'     => 'id'
                )
        ),
        'filter' => false
    ], 'entity_id');

    return $this;
}

}
```

**Edit**:
I thought to remove 'url' in 'actions' and uncomment 'onclick'. Then in $javascript I can make a Ajax.Request to the controller. The problem is that I don't know how to pass the order_id as a parameter.